# Why can't I connect to PSN?

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, psn, wifi

I have a PS3 that connects fine when using wired Ethernet, but when I connect to the same Router via Wifi, the PS3 obtains an IP address correctly, but fails to connect to the PSN.

How do I get the Wifi connection to work like the Wired connection?

Note: I tried connecting a laptop via wifi to the same router and the internet browser works fine, but internet browser on PS3 fails. (This seems to indicate it's a PS3 specific issue).

Note 2: I've tried a second PS3 with the same results.

#### Further Info:

When I review the PS3s network settings once connected via Wifi, they seem to be equivalent to the settings it has when connected directly.

The Wifi Router I'm connecting to is set up in bridging mode and connected to another router/modem to actually talk to the internet.

Comment: Can you get on the internet at all from the PS3? (Try the Internet Browser) or is it just PSN that is giving you issues?

Comment: Internet browser also fails to find anything.

Comment: I would suspect something is awry with the WiFi bridge pass through to the router - perhaps it's restricting the ports that the PS3 needs to authenticate and allow network connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the router.

The router I was using was an old cable-modem/router. It wasn't correctly bridging the internet from the Wireless network.

I replaced it with a DD-WRT router (physically a DIR-330 or something), reset to factory defauilts... and it all just worked.